# Upgrading jQuery from version 1.3.1 to 1.6.1

Tags: jquery, upgrade

I am at present researching the upgrade of jQuery 1.3.1 to 1.6.1

I have read the documentation found on the jQuery site detailing what's new in each of the releases since 1.3.1

http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

I have a very large codebase, some of which I inherited, a lot of which I have added to.

I can run two instances of the site side by side, one with jQuery 1.3.1 and one with jQuery 1.6.1

So I guess my question is, has anyone ever done an upgrade from 1.3.1 to 1.6.1 and did you run into a lot of problems?

Also, other than those three links, is there a difinitive list of changes anywhere?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading jquery to a newer version will raise many js bugs. Before upgrading, make sure that the other jquery plugins, like jquery validator, datepicker, drag-drop, etc.. will be compatible.